# Error launching query in GAE Firestore DatastoreException: no matching index found

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with executing a query on Firestore in Google App Engine. Insertion is successful. But when he tries to run a simple query I get the following error:

```java
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: no matching index found.
at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:128)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:113)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.runQuery(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:181)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:180)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:177)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.runQuery(DatastoreImpl.java:176)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.sendRequest(QueryResultsImpl.java:73)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.<init>(QueryResultsImpl.java:57)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:170)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:161)
...
Caused by: 
com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: no matching index found., code=FAILED_PRECONDITION
at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:136)
at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:185)
at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:96)
at com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.runQuery(Datastore.java:119)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.runQuery(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:179)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:180)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:177)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.runQuery(DatastoreImpl.java:176)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.sendRequest(QueryResultsImpl.java:73)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.<init>(QueryResultsImpl.java:57)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:170)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:161)
```

The query I run is as follows:

```java
Query<Entity> q = Query.newEntityQueryBuilder()
                .setKind(tableName)
                .setOrderBy(OrderBy.asc("t"))
                .setFilter(PropertyFilter.le("t", 1000))
                .build();
QueryResults<Entity> result = datastore.run(q);
```

It doesn't seem to me to be a query that needs an index. For only one property I read that the index is created automatically. However, I created a single-field index on firebase. But I always get the same error.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: isn't there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your Datastore query is that the order of the functions was altered.

First filter and then order by.

```java
Query<Entity> q = Query.newEntityQueryBuilder()
                .setKind(tableName)
                .setFilter(PropertyFilter.le("t", 1000))
                .setOrderBy(OrderBy.asc("t"))
                .build();
QueryResults<Entity> result = datastore.run(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in indexes can be used in very specific cases. Some cases always require a composite index, your appears to be one of them. From [Index configuration](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#index_configuration):

> For more complex queries, an application must define composite, or
>   manual, indexes. Composite indexes are required for queries of the
>   following form:
>
> ...
>
> - Queries with one or more filters and one or more sort orders

You have both a filter and a sort order in your query.